# Converting between ASCII, Binary, Octal, and Hexadecimal

Tags: java

Are there any libraries and/or built-in utilities that can facilitate the conversion of data between ASCII, Binary, Octal, and Hexadecimal?

Currently, I primarily need to convert ASCII to Binary, Octal, or Hexadecimal. At a later point, the starting and ending notations will be any of the aforementioned notations.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What are you converting, data or data representation?

Comment: @Goran Jovic: I'll be converting data representations. For example, I might have a datestamp of `20110523` which I need to convert into binary form or a id number of `n253d106a` that I need to convert into hex form.

Comment: @Goran: What do you mean? Apparently you are trying to distinguish between a number as a concept, like "this many fingers", and a representation of that number in numerals. But once you make that distinction, it is meaningless to talk about whether "this many fingers" is decimal or octal. So your question makes no sense.

Comment: @DanMore: Then, I guess you can easily write any to any base converter with these two methods.

Comment: @Jay: are you seriously suggesting that a programmer never has to transform ASCII text to, say, hexadecimal and vice-versa?  Did Java creators not understand the "concept" by providing *Integer.parseInt(String, radix)*?  If the OP's question makes no sense, maybe you could enlighten us as to when, say, *Integer.parseInt("cafebabe", 16)* makes sense?  You could also explain how Oli Charlesworth got +4 upvotes for his answer to a question that makes no sense?  But I've got to warn you: I may find your new comment too "conceptual" to grasp ;)

Comment: @Jay: The purpose of my question was exactly to determine whether Dan's question makes sense or not. And it does. I really did see some questions in the style of *are "this many fingers" decimal or octal?*

Comment: @Syntax: `parseInt(String, radix)` doesn't convert from ASCII to (say) hex; it converts from an ASCII representation of hex to an int.  This is the important distinction that Goran is alluding to.

Comment: @SyntaxT3rr0r: No, I was building up to accusing Goran of being pedantic. It's meaningless to talk about converting a "conceptual" number between bases because a number as a concept has no base. It is not at all meaningless to talk about displaying a conceptual number in different bases. In practice, we routinely gloss over the distinction between a number and a string of numerals, which is a perfectly good thing to do. When the difference matters, fine, let's talk about it. When it doesn't, ignore it.

Comment: A technical point that might be valid to bring up is that we technically don't convert from ASCII to Hex or Octal. We convert from the internal format to Hex or Octal or Decimal or whatever. Hex and Octal and Decimal are all ASCII. Internal format is not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Integer.toString(int,int)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString%28int,%20int%29) and [Integer.parseInt(String,int)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28int,%20int%29) do this...

Comment: ... and `Integer.parseInt(String s, int radix)` does it in the other direction